# Excel VBA copy and paste tab and by auto filter and delete hidden rows error message out of memory

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if i could get your advice.

I have the below code which works for copying and creating additional tabs by splitting values from a column into 2 tabs and on each tab it applies an autofilter.

However when it creates the 3rd tab it shows an error message that there is not enough memory to continue.

I think that the deleting hidden rows as part of the auto-filter is causing the code to fall down but i have tried to amend the code to clear memory etc but it keeps failing.

Can i please get your help!!

```
Option Explicit


'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Module    : Module1
' DateTime  : 24/09/2006 22:48
' Updated   : 2014
' Author    : Roy Cox (royUK)
' Website   :  more examples
' Purpose   :  Create a sheet for each unique name in data
' Disclaimer; This code is offered as is with no guarantees. You may use it in your
'             projects but please leave this header intact.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Sub ExtractToSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range, rList As Range, rDelete As Range
    Dim rCl As Range
    Dim sNm As String


    Const Crit1 As String = "Category"
    Const Crit2 As String = "Store"


    Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
    On Error GoTo exit_Proc
    'extract a list of unique names
    'first clear existing list
    With ws
        Set rData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear
        rData.Columns(4).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), Unique:=True


        Set rList = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).CurrentRegion
        Set rList = rList.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rList.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                              rList.Columns.Count)


        For Each rCl In rList
            sNm = rCl.Text


            ''///delete any previously created sheets(only if required-NB uses UDF)
            If WksExists(sNm) Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Sheets(sNm).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
            Select Case sNm
            Case "Store", "Category"
                ''/// ignore these names
            Case Else
                Sheets("sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                With ActiveSheet
                    .Name = sNm


                    If Not .AutoFilterMode Then .Range("A1").AutoFilter
                    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$206").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>Store" _
                                                              , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Category"
                    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$206").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=sNm


                    With Sheets(sNm).AutoFilter.Range
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Set rDelete = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1) _
                                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If Not rDelete Is Nothing Then rDelete.EntireRow.Delete
                    End With
                    ''/// Remove the AutoFilter
                    .AutoFilterMode = False
                    .Range("A1").Select
                End With


            End Select


        Next rCl
    End With


    MsgBox "Report completed", vbInformation, "Done"
clean_up:
    ws.Columns(Columns.Count).ClearContents        'remove temporary list
    rData.AutoFilter        ''///switch off AutoFilter
    Exit Sub
exit_Proc:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Resume clean_up
End Sub








Function WksExists(wksName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WksExists = CBool(Len(Worksheets(wksName).Name) > 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the "On Error Resume Next" statements and put

```
msgbox(Err.Description)
```

under the exit_Proc: handler to see what is going on.